# Changing the style of a single Navigation Bar Item (BottomNavigationBarItem) in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way in Flutter to achieve a navigation bar with a bottom navigation bar item having a different style as in the picture below. I manage to generate the bottom navigation bar. However, I have no idea how to make a single BottomNavigationBarItem style stand out like in the picture [raised bottom navigation bar item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jlee8.png). Any ideas?

```
child: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
        topRight: Radius.circular(30),
      ),
      child: Theme(
        data: ThemeData(canvasColor: YummzColors.WHITE.color),
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          iconSize: 25,
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          showSelectedLabels: false,
          showUnselectedLabels: false,
          selectedItemColor: YummzColors.GREEN.color,
          unselectedItemColor: YummzColors.GRAY_SHADE_500.color,
          items: _items,
          currentIndex: 1,
          selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(size: 25),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

From the material built in, no.  But you can create your own and import it in.
Here is an example: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vsyjMrZa5OU&t=665s)

Answer (score 0):

There are two packages that i have used to do something like this

- https://pub.dev/packages/convex_bottom_bar
- https://pub.dev/packages/curved_navigation_bar